# Google ignore me after server down

Tags: google-index

One week ago our server went down for 2 days. After one day, Google completely removed my website from search results. Before that it was in average in 2nd position for 3 keywords for about 7 months.

I have been waiting if Google reindex me and give me my position back, But until now no changes seen.

Is there any solution for this dilemma?

**Update:**
I'd made no change to website content or pages before or during the server down.
Webmasters Tools  statistic shows the depth of tragedy.
[image: webmasters-stats]

Comment: Being down for a couple of days would not normally cause a site to disappear from their index.

Comment: @hashem Without additional information to go by, users can only speculate here. If you can add some details to your question, then it will be reviewed.

Comment: Thanks @Dan. When I asked this question I'd thought that's a general problem. But my question don't mention to an individual website. Server down and Google index problems are general issues.

Comment: Sure. If you can identify some circumstances that might have triggered this (i.e., something done on your end), then this might be something others others can specifically address and learn from. Good luck with your site regardless!

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't already into Google Webmaster Tools, I suggest you to sign up, register your site, generate a XML sitemap (you can make these automatically in many sites that offer that service), upload the sitemap to your server and finally submit it to Google through Webmaster Tools.

Comment: I registered it on Webmasters Tools 7 month ago.

Comment: I think you should try that... recrawl the site. It can't hurt.

Comment: In webmaster tools look at the manual actions tabs, it's likely that google has removed your site until action has been take

Comment: Fetching as Google don't return any error and no manual webspam actions found.